# All data not getting stored in DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to save some data from a JSON to DynamoDB but only 283 out of 592 items are getting stored.

here is my code:

```
    r = requests.get(url)
    j = r.json()

    for features in j["accountsWithGeo"]["features"]:
        i = features["properties"]["id"]
        n = features["properties"]["name"]
        table.put_item(Item={'id':i,'name':n})
```

Comment: Where are you checking the item count? If you are checking it in AWS Management console, it would take a few hours to show the correct count. It is not updated real time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now works after doing it like this:

```
def dbWriter(data):
    with table.batch_writer() as batch:
        item_counter=0
        while item_counter<len(data):
            item=data[item_counter]
            batch.put_item(
                Item=item
            )
            item_counter +=1
```